# Intellij IDEA not detect the Project Sdk location

Tags: android

I done with the installation of:
-Android SDK managers with its tools 
-Android 6.0 (API 23) plus 
-Jdk 1.8.0 also done but still Intellij didn't find Project SDK path.
And on choose of jdk 1.8 it give wrong path in dialog box.
Please help me to find out Android SDK manager path.

Comment: right click the  project and select the module setting, select sdk location , the press ok

Comment: if the android studio default location path is C:\Users\usename\AppData\Local\Android